# Return empty list instead of TimeoutError if function times out

Tags: python, timeout

I have a function that currently uses the `@timeout_decorator` decorator to time a function out after a few seconds. However, rather than timing the function out, I would like to return an empty list `[]`. I am open to using other packages/decorators if necessary provided they can be easily installed via PyPi. Here is my current code:

```
import timeout_decorator
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

@timeout_decorator.timeout(5, use_signals=False)
def get_soup(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    # set the User-agent as a regular browser
    session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

    # get the HTML content
    html = session.get(url).content

    # parse HTML using beautiful soup
    soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

Note: If you need an example of a URL that times out, I use https://www.ebay.com

Comment: you can use--> try: your code except: return []

Comment: Actually in this case that doesn't work! If you use that decorator, you will still get a TimeoutError and without it, the function will continue indefinitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put another decorator around it that handles the catches the timeout exception and returns an empty list. If you don't want to write it on your own, you might want to use the @ignore from funcy https://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/flow.html. Assuming you get a TimeoutError exception, your could should look like

```py
import timeout_decorator
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

@ignore(TimeoutError, default=[])
@timeout_decorator.timeout(5, use_signals=False)
def get_soup(url):
    session = requests.Session()
    # set the User-agent as a regular browser
    session.headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"

    # get the HTML content
    html = session.get(url).content

    # parse HTML using beautiful soup
    soup = bs(html, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

Comment: This still just returns a TimeoutError 

Comment: Looks like this works if you specify `timeout_exception=TimeoutError` in the timeout decorator. I thought that was the default anyway but ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Ignore would be something like so:

```
import timeout_decorator

def ignore(func, *args, **kwargs ):
    def main( *args, **kwargs ):
        try:
            return func( *args, **kwargs )
        except TimeoutError as e:
            print( e )
            return []
    return main

@return_lister
@timeout_decorator.timeout(5)
def function_that_times_out():
    input()

function_that_times_out()
```

Comment: This method returns None if the function does not time out. It also  doesn't distinguish between TimeoutError and other types of errors.

Comment: Right, sorry. Change exception to TimeoutError, I'll edit it